# SQL query to fetch record with start and end date from table having single column as date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with below data, here stage (1) cr_date is start date and stage (2) cr_date is end date, and same email can have multiple entries with respect to product id.

```
email            stage    product_id   cr_date
--------------- -------- ------------ ------------
123@g.com        1         1           2019-01-10
123@g.com        1         1           2019-01-11
123@g.com        1         1           2019-01-13
345@g.com        1         1           2019-01-25
123@g.com        2         1           2019-01-28
345@g.com        1         2           2019-01-24
345@g.com        2         1           2019-01-31
789@g.com        1         2           2019-02-10
789@g.com        2         2           2019-02-15
567@g.com        2         2           2019-01-18
```

and I want query to fetch records between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-31, result should be like as below ??

```
email           product_id     start_date       end_date
-------------- ------------ ----------------- --------------
123@g.com        1            2019-01-10        2019-01-28
345@g.com        1            2019-01-25        2019-01-31
```

Comment: We need more information about your expected output.

Comment: For email 345@g.com and product_id = 1 there is only stage = 2. Explain your expected result.

Comment: I want to ignore that entry, because related entry with stage 1 might be of previous month for example `email : 345@g.com    stage : 1        product_id : 1       created_on 2018-12-12`

Comment: Edit your question and explain what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you need to pass specific product_id, FYI I am using table name `users`

```
SELECT A.email,A.product_id,a.cr_date AS start_date,B.cr_date AS end_date 
FROM users A, users B 
WHERE a.email = b.email AND b.stage=2 AND a.stage=1 AND a.cr_date 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
AND b.cr_date  BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
AND a.product_id=1
```

In the case of all products, id use the following:-

```
SELECT A.email,A.product_id,a.cr_date AS start_date,B.cr_date AS end_date 
FROM users A, users B 
WHERE a.email = b.email AND a.product_id=b.product_id AND b.stage=2 AND a.stage=1 AND a.cr_date 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
AND b.cr_date  BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
```

Comment: I want result with any product_id whose entry have both start_date and end_date in given duration ('2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' )

Comment: can you please try now and see the desired results.

Comment: it is failing if I have two extra entry with `email :123@g.com     stage:1    product_id : 1  created_on : 2019-01-12'`  and `email :123@g.com     stage:1    product_id : 1  created_on : 2019-01-10'`

Comment: according to your question and as shown data the query is working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no multiple "1"s or "2"s in a row for an email/product id combination, then you can use `lead()` for the logic.

So, to calculate the start and end dates:

```
select email, product_id, cr_date as start_date, end_date
from (select t.*,
             lead(cr_date) over (partition by email, product_id order by cr_date) as end_date
      from t
     ) t
where stage = 1 and
      cr_date >= '2019-01-01' and
      cr_date < '2019-02-01' and
      end_date >= '2019-01-01' and
      end_date < '2019-02-01';
```

You can replace `lead()` with a correlated subquery in earlier versions of MySQL.